# Elastic Search: query_string query does not match exact phrase in full text search

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using `Elastic search 6.2.3`. We are using the `query_string` `full-text-query` for the `full-text` search. At present, if we search `lazy brown fox` it searches any file that has all these words `lazy`, `brown` and `fox` but it does not look for `exact-phrase` 'lazy brown fox', even default `slop` is `zero`.

Here is an example:

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "fields": [],
      "query": "lazy AND brown AND fox"
    }
  }
}
```

I have looked at the `match-phrase-query` but the issue is that we have to specify the `field name(s)` in `match-phrase-query` whereas, in `string-query`, it's working with a blank array at fields option.

**Please suggest, how to get the exact phrase match results using `query_string` `full text-query`?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of looking at match-phrase query to run phrase query on multiple fields take a look at [multi_match](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html#multi-match-types) which do supports phrase type query

```
POST phrase_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "this is where it should work",
      "fields": [],
      "type": "phrase"
    }
  }
}
```